# Passing PHP variable to HTML code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to pass the variable from my database to an HTML code but it isn't working. If I enter in a numeric value for my Select option it will work but it doesn't work with me trying to reference my class_id. The code I'm basing mine off of is found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). I am writing this code on wordpress also.

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT course FROM class;");
echo "
<form>
  <select name='department' onchange ='showUser(this.value)'>";
  foreach($result as $results){
    echo "<option selected value='$results->class_id'>$results->course</option>";
  }
  echo" </select>
</form>";
```

Comment: Amazing, already working with Wordpress and objects without understanding the basics of string concatenation.

Comment: @Xorifelse thank you for the helpful comment

Comment: Yes, helpful indeed because the answer you're looking for is somewhere in that comment. You only need to search for it.

Comment: How does your rendered HTML looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to mix your HTML and PHP together, I've fixed a few things for you below. You need to select class_id in your query to use it as the option value, you can't use selected on all options as well. You may want to check if there are actually any results before looping over them too.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT class_id, course FROM class;");
?>
<form>
  <select name="department" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <?php foreach( $results as $result ): ?>
    <option value="<?= $results->class_id ?>"><?= $results->course ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT course FROM class;");
    echo '<form><select name="department" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
  foreach($result as $results){
    echo '<option selected value="'.$results->class_id.'" >'.$results->course.'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select></form>';
```

Answer (score -2):

it is easy and simple for understanding use this code it's working prefect

```
<?php global $wpdb; $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT course FROM class;"); ?>
<form>
    <select name='department' onchange ='showUser(this.value)'>
        <?php foreach($result as $results){ ?>
        <option selected value='<?php echo $results->class_id; ?>'><?php echo $results->course; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```